# macOS: Error: No native build was found for platform

Tags: node.js, macos, nvm

I'm currently using macOS `Monterey` (version `12.6`) and `nvm`. I'm attempting to migrate over to `Node` version `18.0.0` from version `16.13.0` for a Gatsby project to setup `Gatsby 5`.

The Node version is being set in the `.nvmrc` file and is being installed using `nvm`:

```bash
$ nvm install
```

The Node version of `18.0.0` is then being installed, again using `nvm`:

```bash
$ nvm use
```

When I run the `Gatsby` build, which is using `version 4` currently, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=arm64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 armv=8 libc=glibc node=18.0.0
```

The Node version needs to be at least version `18` before we can move to `Gatsby 5`.

I was expecting Node version `18.0.0` to run the development build as this works for Node version `17.9.1`

Answer (score -1):

To set as current node versions.

```
nvm use 14.xx.xx
```

To install a specific node version.

```
nvm install 16.xx.xx
```

To get all the node versions you can install.

```
nvm remote-ls
```

To get all the installed node versions

```
nvm ls
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the issue. The use of `nvm` to change the Node versions is something that is working. The error when running `gatsby develop` is the main issue when moving from `Node` `version 16` to `version 18` and later.